# Create new column based on rule Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I stumble upon on problem with **pandas** dataframe.
I have this dataframe.

```
user    event   diff days
1001    request    45
1001    approve    43
1002    request    44
1002    approve    43
1002    request    42
1003    approve    41
1003    request    40
1003    approve    39
1003    request    38
```

I would like to create new column **Flag** based this rule: we define Problem as not making another request within 45 days after **last** request for each user.

The output should look like this.

```
user    event   diff Days   flag
1001    request    45       Problem
1001    approve    43       Problem
1002    request    44       NoProblem
1002    approve    43       NoProblem
1002    request    42       NoProblem
1003    approve    41       NoProblem
1003    request    40       NoProblem
1003    approve    39       NoProblem
1003    request    38       NoProblem
```

I cannot come up with solution using **np.where** or **np.select**. Any kinds of solution are welcome.

In case you want to play around with this, you can use this to reproduce my dataframe above.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'user': [1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003],
                           'event': ['request', 'approve', 'request', 'approve', 'request', 'approve', 'request', 'approve', 'request'],
                           'Diff Days': [45, 43, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38]})
```

**N.B. I need to flag as problem only cases where we are not making another request within 45 days after last request (column diff days) for each user and event(I imply only request). The rest of fields from event do not play a role.**

Comment: Not sure this is the best sample dataframe. Can a user have multiple requests? Could you provide a better example?

Comment: Nope I need only to flag it when it is above 45.Can we take the latest request? Do you think if I add date it will help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

In the comments, you said you want to flag users where `event` is `request` and `Diff Days >= 45`. Here's how:

```
users_with_problems = df.loc[(df["event"] == "request") & (df["Diff Days"] >= 45), "users"]
df["Flag"] = "No problem"
df.loc[df["user"].isin(users_with_problem), "Flag"] = "Problem"
```

END OF EDIT.

It seems you want `Flag` to display `Problem` across **all the rows** of a user who had a single problem. To do this:

```
df["Flag"] = "No problem"
users_with_problem = df.loc[df["Diff Days"] >= 45, "user"]
df.loc[df["user"].isin(users_with_problem), "Flag"] = "Problem"
```

This returns:

```
user    event  Diff Days        Flag
1001  request         45     Problem
1001  approve         43     Problem
1002  request         44  No problem
1002  approve         43  No problem
1002  request         42  No problem
1003  approve         41  No problem
1003  request         40  No problem
1003  approve         39  No problem
1003  request         38  No problem
```

However, you said you only want to flag a problem if `diff` is 45 or more. You can do this as follows:

```
df["Flag"] = "No Problem"
df.loc[df["Diff Days"] >= 45, "Flag"] = "Problem"
```

This will only flag the users in the rows where `diff >= 45`:

```
user    event  Diff Days        Flag
1001  request         45     Problem
1001  approve         43  No problem
1002  request         44  No problem
1002  approve         43  No problem
1002  request         42  No problem
1003  approve         41  No problem
1003  request         40  No problem
1003  approve         39  No problem
1003  request         38  No problem
```

Comment: Hi. How I can do it if `df["diff"] >= 45 and event == request` only?

Comment: @vasiop I changed the name of "Diff Days" to "diff" in my script because I don't like working with spaces.

If you want to just display `Problem` when `Diff Days` is exactly 45, then change the second line to: `users_with_45 = df.loc[df["Diff Days"] == 45, "user"]`.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: How I can do it for Diff Days >= 45 and event equal to request?

Comment: Oh! Alright: `users_with_problem = df.loc[(df["event"] == "request") & (df["Diff Days] >= 45), "user"]`. I will edit this in my answer.

Comment: Once I run it returns all Problem? Any suggestions ?

Comment: I run it stumble upon this error `KeyError: 'the label [users] is not in the [columns]`. There is mistake in  `users_with_problems = df.loc[(df["event"] == "request") & (df["Diff Days"] >= 45), "users"]`  even replace it with user it gives me incorrect result. I mean flag me both request and approve for user 1001 as Problem only request should be.

Comment: Super kudos for you and god bless you thanks. I found the right syntax thanks to you.
`df["Flag"] = "No Problem"
df.loc[(df["Diff Days"] >= 45) & (df["event"] == "request"), "Flag"] = "Problem"
df`